# Wordpress Plugin function callback by URL

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, url-rewriting, plugins-url

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Rewrite Wordpress URL for a Plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/69768/how-to-rewrite-wordpress-url-for-a-plugin)

I'm creating a plugin for Wordpress. 
Is there any way or API to make plugin receive a path or URL so that it can trigger or output something. I mean something like this

```
add_filter('THE_FILTER_NAME', 'myPluginFunc');
function myPluginFunc($url)
{
    if($url != 'mydesiredurl')
        return;

    echo "this URL path is handled by myplugin";
}
```

or

```
register_urlpath('mydesiredpath', 'mycallbackfunction');
```

and also, if applicable, this url path is registered to my plugin so users cannot assign any page using that url anymore, unless myplugin is deactivated.

EDIT: additional info

i'm creating plugin which need a path to be called as something like webservice, when the site is calling is a way, thedomain.com/myplugin, then what i want is the wordpress system understand that the URL requested is for myplugin, and therefore will execute a function myplugin supplied, which in my case, is simply send email to site admin.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not clear about what you are trying to accomplish or what the path/URL is for, can you explain?

Comment: the URL i want achieve is something like url-rewriting, but instead rewriting url /the-path to /wp-contents/plugin/myplugin/thefile.php, is there any way wordpress will now, that when user request /the-path, call a function spesified by myplugin.

Comment: You could use wordpress built in way to rewrite.

Comment: Why don't you simply create a page with that url/permalink ? And then use a custom template that just call the plugin function (or even place the code in to template). You'll be sure that this url cannot be used by any other page.

Comment: can that be done simply by activating my plugin?