# How to Rewrite Wordpress URL for a Plugin

Tags: plugin-development, url-rewriting, urls, rewrite-rules, endpoints

I am trying to build a Wordpress plugin here with a custom user admin area. What I would like to do is when the user adds /edit at the end of the page, it should open a page from my plugin. So for example

`example.com/page-1/edit` 
should load
`example.com/wp-content/plugins/custom-user-admin-area/index.php?u=page-1`

I am trying to make use of WP_Rewrite but in vain.

```
class MyPlugin {
    function create_rewrite_rules($rules) {
        global $wp_rewrite;
        $newRule = array('([A-Za-z0-9-].+)/edit/' => 'wp-content/plugins/custom-user-admin-area/index.php?u=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1));
        $newRules = $newRule + $rules;
        return $newRules;
    }

    function flush_rewrite_rules() {
        global $wp_rewrite;
        $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
    }

}

$MyPluginCode = new MyPlugin();
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', array($MyPluginCode, 'create_rewrite_rules'));
add_filter('init', array($MyPluginCode, 'flush_rewrite_rules'));
```

Comment: Do not use your plugin URL like that. Plugins can be on a separate domain where the Cookies do not work. Use a custom URL under the main web site instead.

Comment: I might be needing wordpress functions too. So, do you mean create a new php file and load wp-load.php instead? My edit page updates a posts and its custom fields basically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Create an endpoint](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/51450/73). In the callback function for the endpoint call your plugin functions internally, so the whole WordPress environment is available *and* you are still on the same domain, no matter where the [plugin URL](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/15484/73) is.

Plus, make sure not to flush the rewrite rules on every page load, [use the (de)activation hook](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/63693/73) for that.

Comment: care to explain this line I saw that coding style for the first time `isset($vars['epex']) and $vars['epex'] = true;`

Comment: @atif089 That is the same like `if ( isset($vars['epex']) ) {$vars['epex'] = true;}` – just shorter. The part after the `and` will be ignored if the part before that is `false`.

Comment: Thanks, another thing is how shall I handle POST requests on the same URL, as of now it does not seem to handle POST requests on the same page.

Comment: @atif089 [Ask a new question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?title=POST%20requests%20on%20endpoints&tags=forms%20url-rewriting) for that please.

Comment: over here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71369/creating-a-custom-registration-page-with-url-rewriting