# Plugin “virtual” page

Tags: plugins, pages, customization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Rewrite Wordpress URL for a Plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/69768/how-to-rewrite-wordpress-url-for-a-plugin)

## Question

I am trying to create a plugin that adds an additional page to a Wordpress public site and allows the plugin to control the pages content. I don't want the page to appear in the admin sites editable page list and I dont want it to be included in the menu generation function  wp_page_menu();. The only way the page should be access is via a url. Example www.mysite.com/my-account/

## Example

I have a site www.mysite.com, and I navigate to www.mysite.com/my-account/ I will get a 404 error page.

If I activate my plugin then navigate to www.mysite.com/my-account/ I should see the content defined by my plugin and not a 404 error.

I have currently implemented a not so elegant solution and was sondering if there is a better way to do this?

## Not so elegant solution

```
$object = new MyPlugin()
add_action('template_redirect', array($object, 'override404'));
add_filter('wp_title', array($object, 'title'));

class MyPlugin {

public function override404() {
    global $path;

    switch ($path) {
        case "/my-account/" :
            // Use this header instruction to fix 404 headers
            // produced by url rewriting...
            header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');
            // Hook into wp_title filter hook
            include (get_template_directory() . '/my-account.php');
            exit;
            break;
        case "/bla/" :
            // Use this header instruction to fix 404 headers
            // produced by url rewriting...
            header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');
            // Hook into wp_title filter hook
            include (get_template_directory() . '/bla.php');
            exit;
            break;
    }
}

public function title($title) {
    if (is_404()) {
        global $path;

        switch ($path) {
            case "/my-account/" :
                $title = 'My Account';
                break;
            case "/bal/" :
                $title = 'Bla';
                break;
        }

        $title .= " | ";
    }
    // You can do other filtering here, or
    // just return $title
    return $title;
}
}
```

Comment: See also http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/54583/how-can-i-use-wordpress-functions-in-my-stylesheet

Comment: Toscho, i'm not sure how the question you mentioned is relevant to this problem at all?

Comment: The endpoint is exactly the URL you need for your plugin.