# Use custom clean URLs for a plug in

Tags: plugin-development, url-rewriting, slug

I've created a plug in that displays a list of items from the database.
I need to link from an item to the item description page, however instead of the link looking like:

```
item_description.php?item_id=2
```

I'd like it to look like:

```
products/this-is-the-product-name
```

How do I create the page I'm linking to and set it to be directed there?
How can I read the slug?
Thank you for any ideas!

Comment: what are products exactly? a custom post type?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/69768/how-to-rewrite-wordpress-url-for-a-plugin)?

Comment: I've created a page that with a shortcode lists all the, for example, cars in a database. I want to be able to click on a car and go to cars/ford-mustang which will then show me specific info on the selected car