# Display Plugin information on specific url

Tags: plugins, database, urls, slug

So I created a WP plugin with its own unique DB tables. I chose this approach as opposed to using a custom post type because of relationships I needed between the tables. So I'm not even sure how to word this, but basically what I need to do is display my information when a user accesses a specific url such as (http://website.com/pluginname?query=number). I don't even know if you could do this with WP, and I know the easy way to do it would be with a shortcode or template file but I want to avoid that because I want this to be as simple as possible for the actual person using the plugin. Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/69768/how-to-rewrite-wordpress-url-for-a-plugin)?

Comment: @toscho no I hadn't. Thanks! Should I just create a rewrite rule that points to a php file in my plugin directory? Also do rewrite rules allow for $_GET[] querys? I'm kind of new to this.

Comment: Register an endpoint, WordPress will create the rewrite rules for your plugin then automatically.